# Bubble Sort in JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Bubble sort program. It shows error.but I don't understand why?I am new  in java

```
public static  void main(String[] args) {
    int []arr={12,23,43,34,3,6,7,1,9,6};
        {  
              int temp;
              for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
              {  
                for (int j=0;j<arr.length-i;j++ )
                {
                  if (arr[j]>arr[j+1])
                 {  
                     temp=arr[j];
                     arr[j+1]=arr[j];
                     arr[j+1]=temp;
                  }
                }
              } 
            }
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
         {
             System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
         }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Asus HP! Would you be so kind as to share the error message with us? We can't read your mind, you know.

Comment: Also, is this homework? If so, please tag as homework.

Comment: Error::Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at SortExperiment.main(SortExperiment.java:33)    Line 33: if (arr[j]>arr[j+1])

Comment: Actually, I would suggest to look at Wikipedia's bubble sort, there is a pseudocode, which you can easily, step by step rewrite to Java and in every milestone, you might check your results, whether they are as expected.

Answer (score 3):

What's the error?

I suspect that it's `IndexOutOfBoundsException`? It's probably the `if` statement where you use `j + 1`, when `j == arr.length - 1` when `i == 0`.

As it's homework, I'll leave it up to you to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code......

```
public class TestBubbleSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int unsortedArray[] = {10, 97, 6, 23, 0, -45, 697, -1000, 1, 0}; //Random set of numbers for example.
        int i;

        bubbleSort(unsortedArray, unsortedArray.length); //Pass the array to be sorted and its length.

        System.out.println("After sorting, the list elements are: "); //Just to show you it worked. :)

        for(i=0; i<unsortedArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(unsortedArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    private static void bubbleSort(int[] unsortedArray, int length) {
        int temp, counter, index;

        for(counter=0; counter<length-1; counter++) { //Loop once for each element in the array.
            for(index=0; index<length-1-counter; index++) { //Once for each element, minus the counter.
                if(unsortedArray[index] > unsortedArray[index+1]) { //Test if need a swap or not.
                    temp = unsortedArray[index]; //These three lines just swap the two elements:
                    unsortedArray[index] = unsortedArray[index+1];
                    unsortedArray[index+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alohci homework tag was added later....... moreover i don't deserve +1 and then -2 for my correct answer... that too with explanation...so the OP can understand it better

Comment: @Thanks..............................

Comment: Bubble sort questions are *always* homework. Last time I wrote a bubble sort was in Computer Programming 101, somewhat 'back in the day'. Never used one professionally and never will.

Comment: +1. This is the best website to learn/teach on the internet, but java isn't a simple language to learn like high level languages such as Ruby or Python. I agree that the guy should have asked his question giving more details, but WE should try to help him (why not with the code and comments?). I don't find java an easy language to learn and to debug (i'm used with php, which is really simple, faster and "cleaner" to debug..

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this code , It is in reverse order but you will get the idea .

```
public class SortArray 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr={4,6,4,2,764,23,23};
        sort(arr);
    }
    static void sort(int[] arr)
    {
        int k;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<arr.length-1;j++)
                {
                    if(arr[i]<arr[j+1])
                    {
                        k=arr[j+1];
                        arr[j+1]=arr[i];
                        arr[i]=k;
                    }
                }
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        //insert random value in array
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("no of element");
        int noEle=sc.nextInt();
        int[] eleArr=new int[noEle] ;//storing element in this array
        for(int i=0;i<noEle;i++)
        {
            eleArr[i]=sc.nextInt();//enter element for storing 
        }
        for(int i=0;i<eleArr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<eleArr.length-1;j++)
        {
            if(eleArr[j]>eleArr[j+1])
            {//nothing but swaping logic without taking third variable
                eleArr[j]=eleArr[j]+eleArr[j+1];
                eleArr[j+1]=eleArr[j]-eleArr[j+1];
                eleArr[j]=eleArr[j]-eleArr[j+1];
            }
        }
        }
        //getting sorted elemen as bubblesort
        for(int i=0;i<noEle;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(eleArr[i]+" ");  
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Try This Code definitely  it will work for bubble sort

Answer (score -1):

You can view across this code:

```
public static void BubbleSort(int[] Array){

    for(int i = Array.length ; i>0 ; i--)
    {
            for(int j=0;j<i-1;j++){

                if(Array[j]>Array[j+1])
                    Swap(Array,j,j+1);
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you should explain your code